# $animate addClass not working in angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

While this demo works perfectly with angular 1.2, I can't make it work with 1.3.

http://plnkr.co/edit/r0aAPnTqoBfRFNBwQSpY?p=preview

I read the changelog, and find out that the $animate service had several breaking changes from 1.2 to 1.3, but I wasn't able to make this animation work.

The expected result is, that the `dialog` div appears with a `zoomIn` animation, but with 1.3 it appearn without any animation.

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div dialog></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**dialog.html**

```
<div class="dialog">
  I'm a dialog!
  <button ng-click="addClass()">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="removeClass()">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
    angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]);

    angular.module("app").directive("dialog", function($animate) {
      return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "dialog.html",
        link: function(scope, el) {
          $animate.addClass(el, "open");
        }
      }
    });
```

and finally **style.css**

```
/* Styles go here */

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.dialog {
  display: none;
}

.dialog.open {
  display: block;
}

.dialog.open-add {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  -moz-animation-name: zoomIn;
  -o-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
  -o-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from documentation

> this will be skipped if no CSS transitions or keyframes are defined on the **-add-active** or base CSS class.

You should add your transition not to `.open-add` class but to `.open-add-active`

Comment: I tried that way, but the same result: http://plnkr.co/edit/BSyDaE2Nhvwckk09OLcr?p=preview. If you have a working demo, please link it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. Based on it I was able to fix my own version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uZ0TJrNAiyyQ1R1TXEIo?p=preview